# Remove part of the lines except few characters?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking for the way to delete part of the line, but there is some text static, which doesn`t change. Example:

```
http://example1.com/index.php?static=bread&dasd
http://example2.com/?static=oil&gas&check
```

So I want to remove `&dasd` from the first line and `&gas&check` the from second line. I have thousands of lines of this and found some difficulties, as the domain and string after `static=` can contain different number of characters. In addition, different number of characters can come before the `&` sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capturing group and backreference.

Find what:

```
(static=[^&]*).*
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find using the regex:

```
&.*
```

and replace with blank.

Comment: This is the way. By the way, this question is a trifle.